# How to get hits data from elasticsearch in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch response stored as a String value in java,How to process only hits data

Comment: ...what format is the response in? Can you parse that somehow...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, you want to retrieve all data as `Car` type. Your query response is store in `searchResponse` variable, get all hits and serialize them to the objects. 
Look at the example below:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

var flowers = new ArrayList<Flower>();

Arrays.stream(searchResponse.getHits().getHits()).forEach(hit ->
                    cars.add(gson.fromJson(hit.getSourceAsString(), Car.class)));
```

Of course, I am using gson to serialize the JSON to the object.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to access it from Java is to use the official [Java REST API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high.html) from Elastic. The API will let you work with Java objects instead of processing the data yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert the json string to a json/map object, either using gson, Jackson, or other method.

Then, once you have a Map, the hits are under: hits.hits key, as an array of maps, each map in the array represent a hit, with its metadata. The original doc is under the key _source in each hit.

I also highly recommend reading elasticsearch docs, which are good source.